# inserting element through iterator c++

Tags: c++, insert, set, structure

I am trying to  insert element into set "teachers". teachers is is set which is part of structure, school. And school structures are inside another set called town. I am trying to put teacher "Green" into school where "Brown" is a headmaster. I used find to find the school but i cant get him in. operators <, == is defined to co compare headmasters.

```
bool operator<(const School& l, const School& r){
  return (l.headmaster) < (r.headmaster);
}
bool operator==(const School& l, const School& r){
  return (l.headmaster) == (r.headmaster);
}

struct School {
    string headmaster;
    set <string> teachers;
};

set<School>::iterator it;
set <School> town;
// now I alocated few schools and insert them into town, 
School *pSchool = new School(): // i will use pSchool to find school with brown as headmaster
pSchool > headmaster  = "Brown"; // 
it = rozvrh.find(*pSchool);
cout << it->headmaster // gives Brown
it->teachers.insert("Green"); /// error
```

edited .. error

||=== ulohaa1, Debug ===|
/home/ulohaa1/main.cpp||In function ‘bool transform(const char*, const char*)’:|
/home/ulohaa1/main.cpp|84|error: no matching function for call to ‘std::set >::insert(std::string&) const’|
/home/michal/Desktop/prog/ulohaa1/main.cpp|84|note: candidates are:|
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_set.h|407|note: std::pair, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<_Key>::other>::const_iterator, bool> std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(const value_type&) [with _Key = std::basic_string, _Compare = std::less >, _Alloc = std::allocator >, typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Key, std::_Identity<_Key>, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<_Key>::other>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator >, std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type = std::basic_string] |
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_set.h|407|note:   no known conversion for implicit ‘this’ parameter from ‘const std::set >*’ to ‘std::set >*’|
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_set.h|444|note: std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator, const value_type&) [with _Key = std::basic_string, _Compare = std::less >, _Alloc = std::allocator >, std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator >, std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator >, std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type = std::basic_string]|
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_set.h|444|note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided|
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_set.h|464|note: template void std::set::insert(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = _InputIterator, _Key = std::basic_string, _Compare = std::less >, _Alloc = std::allocator >]|
||=== Build finished: 7 errors, 0 warnings ===|

Thx for your help guys

Comment: C++ is case sensitive so the line {School *pSchool = new school():} shouldn't compile (not to mention the colon at the end of the line.

Comment: @Andy, unless `school` is secretly inherited from `School`, but judging from the OP's question, that is unlikely

Comment: @awesomeyi Agreed. Perhaps the OP can clarify.

Comment: How can you have a set<School>?  That alone will not compile since a School has no less-than ordering defined.  Better yet, post a real, compilable, but small program.  Hastily posting code and having others try to figure out all the typos doesn't help.

Comment: `/// error` means what exactly??

Comment: school was missclick .. I have uppercase in my code

Comment: @user2109307 - Again, no way can you have a set<School>, given the way you've defined School.  You should have gotten either a compiler error or linker error due to a missing operator < for School.

Comment: @user2109307 < is global overloaded. Its writen in the text up there

Comment: @user2109307 - so you tell us, given two School objects, which object would be placed before the other object?  What criteria do you use?  Do you sort on headmaster?  That is what the compiler is telling you -- it needs to know how to order the School's correctly when they are placed in the set.

Comment: What global operator?  I don't see anything except a lot of gibberish.  Are you sure you're learning C++ and not another language?

Comment: its cut from code about 200 lines. The code is working till i add it->teachers.insert("Green");

Comment: How hard is it to just post the *full* operator code?  And if it worked, why the compiler error?  Don't "cut code" -- all it does is make it look like you don't know how to write code, and everyone is going to comment on it.

Comment: PaulMcKenzie i know. it looks horible, its program for the school and my school is very strict on not posting part of homeworks online. i am actualy sorry for that

Comment: @user2109307 - the error you posted suggests that you didn't write the overloaded < correctly.  So what are you expecting from us, if not to show you how to write a correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler error you have suggests that you did not overload operator < for your School type:

```
#include <set>
#include <string>

struct School
{
    std::string headmaster;
    std::set<std::string> teachers;
    bool operator<(const School& s) const { return headmaster < s.headmaster; }
};
```

If you need to update a school in the set you need to

1) Find the school in the set

2) If found, save the value to a temp school

3) Update the temp school

4) Erase the school from the set and insert the temp school to the set

That is the nature of the set container.  To update an item means removal and insertion with the updated item.  So basically this:

```
// we will search for Mr Brown's school and add a teacher
School searchSchool;
searchSchool.headmaster = "Brown";
std::set<School>::iterator it = mainSchool.find(searchSchool);

// if found, add the teacher
if (it != mainSchool.end())
{
    // save the school
    School theSchool = *it;
    theSchool.teachers.insert("A new teacher");
    mainSchool.erase(it);
    mainSchool.insert(theSchool);
}
```

The mainSchool is your "global" set.

Edit:  If using map (which I believe is superior), the code can be as simple as this:

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>
typedef std::set<std::string> StringSet;
typedef std::map<std::string, StringSet>  SchoolMap;

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    SchoolMap allSchools;
    allSchools.insert(make_pair("Brown", StringSet()));
    allSchools.insert(make_pair("Smith", StringSet()));

    // search for Mr Brown's school
    SchoolMap::iterator it = allSchools.find("Brown");

    // if found, add the teacher
    if (it != allSchools.end())
    // save the teacher
        it->second.insert("A new teacher");
}
```

Comment: The other thing you need to realize is that to change a value in a set, you need to remove the old value and replace it with the updated value.  See my updated answer.

Comment: and if i change struct school to have only a pointer on set techers? Pointer would stay same if i give element into it.

Comment: Don't use pointers in a set.  Maybe you should be using a map, and not a set.  The key is the headmaster, and the values can be the set of teachers.  Then the map's items can be changed without erasing the whole key.

Comment: hmm. i am afraid, of losing time on find functions with map.(I just realized it have similar find speed..)ok map sounds good

Comment: See my updated answer on using map.  A map has logarithmic lookup time, just as a set does.  So there is no slowdown in speed.

Comment: huh,  you just totaly solved it man.. works fine now. You saved my life .